# ScrollViewer scrolls back on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, grid, scrollviewer

I have created a page where there's alot of input from the user. So the User should be able to scroll down to be able to press a Upload button. To scroll down on the page I have used a ScrollViewer outside a grid. I am able to scroll but the page keeps scrolling back after scrolling down.

Here is my code:

```
  <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanelButtom" Grid.Row="1" >
            <ScrollViewer >
                <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="black">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="154" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="326" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Height="109" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="167" Margin="23,19,0,0" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSoruce, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBox Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,161,0,0" Name="nameInput" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="430" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock Height="56" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,134,0,0" Name="nameLabel" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" FontSize="25" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="25" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,238,0,0" Name="descriptionLabel" Text="Description" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" />
                    <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,265,0,0" Name="descriptionInput" Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="430" IsEnabled="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="25" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,343,0,0" Name="locationLabel" Text="Location" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" />
                    <TextBlock Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,384,0,0" Name="locationInput" Text="{Binding Path=Location, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="401" Loaded="locationInput_Loaded" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <toolkit:ListPicker SelectionMode="Multiple" FullModeHeader="CATEFORIES" x:Name="ListPickerCategories" CacheMode="BitmapCache" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,492,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="401" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Height="78"></toolkit:ListPicker>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="25" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,436,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Categories" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" />
                    <Button Content="Upload" Height="86" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,604,0,0" Name="UploadButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="411" Click="UploadButton_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
```

What can be the cause of this problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Use `StackPanels` to put elements one below the other. Remove all your `margins`, `height`, `width` and other absolute positioning stuff

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanelButtom" Grid.Row="1" >
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- elements here -->
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. but at last i solved it, i just used the Height property to do this. Please do the following steps

- First create a ScrollViewer
- Indide the ScrollViewer create a container(eg: Grid/StackPanel/Border etc...) and put every controlls inside it.
- Set fixed Height for ScrollViewer and the Container (Note: Height of container should be greater than ScrollViewer's Height)

See the below Code

```
<ScrollViewer Height="500">
        <Grid Name="Container" Height="700">
            <TextBox/>
            <TextBox/>
            <TextBox/>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Now you can scroll the container Grid Even the KeyBoard shown or even focus on a TextBox.